# How to add Trackchanges (del/ins) in a doc?

Tags: java, docx4j

I need to manipulate docx documents in java and I have just started evaluating docx4j. So far I have manage to perform some actions on my document (add text, remove paragraph, isolate a piece of the document...) but I still have problem managing Trackchanges (inserts and delete). I would appreciate if somebody brings light into this subject because so far [this](http://www.docx4java.org/forums/docx-java-f6/indicating-deleted-paragraph-track-changes-t1177.html) is the closest I have found to proper documentation in the matter.

To illustrate the problem, I will give a small sample of what I want to achieve. I have the following docx in Flat OPC format:

```
<w:pPr>
    <w:pStyle w:val="Normal"/>
</w:pPr>
<w:sdt>
    <w:sdtContent>
        <w:r>
            <w:t>First deleted part</w:t>
        </w:r>
    </w:sdtContent>
</w:sdt>
<w:sdt>
    <w:sdtContent>
        <w:r>
            <w:t>(</w:t>
        </w:r>
        <w:r>
            <w:t>(second deleted part)</w:t>
        </w:r>
    </w:sdtContent>
</w:sdt>
```

I need to add the trackchanges (the code was generated by Word itself, not programatically):

```
<w:pPr>
    <w:pStyle w:val="Normal"/>
</w:pPr>
<w:customXmlDelRangeStart w:id="4" w:author="AddedProgramatically" w:date="2014-11-06T18:22:00Z"/>
<w:sdt>
    <w:sdtContent>
        <w:customXmlDelRangeEnd w:id="4"/>
        <w:del w:id="5" w:author="AddedProgramatically" w:date="2014-11-06T18:22:00Z">
            <w:r>
                <w:delText>First deleted part</w:delText>
            </w:r>
        </w:del>
        <w:customXmlDelRangeStart w:id="8" w:author="AddedProgramatically" w:date="2014-11-06T18:22:00Z"/>
    </w:sdtContent>
</w:sdt>
<w:customXmlDelRangeEnd w:id="8"/>
<w:customXmlDelRangeStart w:id="9" w:author="AddedProgramatically" w:date="2014-11-06T18:22:00Z"/>
<w:sdt>
    <w:sdtEndPr/>
    <w:sdtContent>
        <w:customXmlDelRangeEnd w:id="9"/>
        <w:del w:id="10" w:author="AddedProgramatically" w:date="2014-11-06T18:22:00Z">
            <w:r>
                <w:delText>(second deleted part)</w:delText>
            </w:r>
        </w:del>
        <w:customXmlDelRangeStart w:id="15" w:author="AddedProgramatically" w:date="2014-11-06T18:22:00Z"/>
    </w:sdtContent>
</w:sdt>
<w:customXmlDelRangeEnd w:id="15"/>
<w:sdt>
    <w:sdtContent>
        <w:ins w:id="16" w:author="AddedProgramatically" w:date="2014-11-06T18:21:00Z">
            <w:r>
                <w:t>First inserted part</w:t>
            </w:r>
        </w:ins>
    </w:sdtContent>
</w:sdt>
<w:sdt>
    <w:sdtContent>
        <w:ins w:id="19" w:author="AddedProgramatically" w:date="2014-11-06T18:21:00Z">
            <w:r>
                <w:t>(second inserted part)</w:t>
            </w:r>
        </w:ins>
    </w:sdtContent>
</w:sdt>
```

In my java code I have manage to copy the sdt and add it to the final document. What I have a missing is the most complicated part: adding the trackchanges. My code so far:

```
ObjectFactory factory = Context.getWmlObjectFactory();
CTTrackChange cttc = factory.createCTTrackChangeRange();
cttc.setParent(para);
cttc.setAuthor(userPhraseology);
final SdtRun copy = XmlUtils.deepCopy(sdt); // And now? How to add the trackchanges into the sdt?
```

Thank you very much for an enlightenment.

Comment: If you upload the docx containing the XML Word generated to webapp.docx4java.org/OnlineDemo/PartsList.html then click through to document.xml part, then click on the relevant XML element, it ought to generate suitable code for you.

Comment: Thank you very much. I have just started with docx4j and I did not know this webapp. It seems is going to be extremely useful.